# JQuery post and load with Animations

Tags: jquery

I am building an application using Jquery load and post functions.

When a link is clicked it sets off a series of animations and then uses the load function to load a bunch of stuff in a div. I also have some buttons that post and then reload the data.

My issue arises when I frantically click link after link. It queues up load and post functions and animations and bogs down. Is there a way to just stop and remove any current animations and load / post functions that have been executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
.stop( [clearQueue], [jumpToEnd] )
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
.stop(true, true)
```

chain this before your next animation effect and it will first jump to the final frame of the current animation queue, and also remove everything from the queue.